# What Kind of Weapon Do the Giants Use In The Film 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2'?

Tags: harry-potter, weapon

**What kind of weapon do the giants use in the film *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2*?**

[image: Giant in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2*]

I thought at first the weapon might be a scythe, but it's clearly not. It's like half a circle of iron mounted on a mast of some kind. **What kind of weapon is this?**

To the untrained eye like mine -- and I know *nothing* about weapons in Fantasy -- it doesn't seem like a particularly efficient weapon; it's blunt, it seems ungainly, and from scenes in the movie it seems like a slow weapon to wield. **Is this a particularly useful weapon?** Perhaps I just don't know much about it.

<sub>Sorry for the poor image quality. It was the best I could find.</sub>

Comment: Blunt isn't "inefficient" - most longswords were not razor sharp, and neither are machetes - they rely more on their weight for damage. That weapon in the hands of a giant looks like it could easily do a lot of damage

Comment: They used **large** weapons.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a 月牙鏟, AKA a [Monk's Spade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk%27s_spade) or Crescent Moon Spade.

Answer (score 13):

It is most definitely not an "inefficient" or unuseful weapon if wielded by a proficient person (like Gordon Liu in the classic [The 36th Chamber of Shaolin](http://www.lovehkfilm.com/reviews/36th_chamber.htm)).

[image]

I'm not aware of the weapon having its own name, at least in English speaking world. Reverse horizontally mounted half-moon it is :)

It may actually be a good weapon to wield by a giant, as the giants are prone to fight OTHER giants. One of the weapon's greatest uses would be to trap opponent's neck, which is probably more effective than using a regular blade on a giant's tough hide (akin to russian bear hunting strategy using a 2-bladed pitchfork)

Comment: @Pureferret - I'm an expert on bear wrestling. *NodNod*

Comment: Thanks! I tried to be careful to say that it *appears* to be an ungainly weapon, but I'm not at all even remotely versed in weaponry, so I could be wrong. I totally hadn't thought of the neck trapping aspect within the giant community itself. So I suppose when faced with little people, the other choice would be to hit them with the half moon or sweep them aside. :)

Comment: Although the giant in the question's picture doesn't seem to have a neck...  =P

Answer (score 7):

I was wondering this for a long while. I now think it's a torn down quidditch ring. This occurred to me when watching the final film last time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Chinese weapon called a "Monk's Spade". Traditionally, the shovel like spade on one end was placed so that traveling monks could properly bury and corpses they came across; and the smaller crescent moon on the other side was to be used as a weapon to defend against bandit attacks. This evolved into the Monk's spade weapon.   Cheers :)   Reference: I own one, and have been practicing Shaolin Kempo Kung Fu for 5 years.

Answer (score 4):

I'm really late to this party but I always thought it was one of the goals from the Quidditch pitch.  The size is abbout right and if I remember correctly the scene you posted is after the pitch was being destroyed.

[image]